# bigcache is getting reset after each set call

Tags: go, caching

I am trying to play a bit with bigcache as it seems the fastest cache library for go ATM.

i am having a weird issue tho, everytime i call `Set()` the cache is being deleted/overrided.

Also, if im only trying to write to cache once and than get it by the key, it does not find the key, and says the cache has 0 items in it.

code:

My `Set()` function, calling bigcache's `Set()`:

```
type MyCache struct {
    Cache *bigcache.BigCache
}

func (c *MyCache) Set(key, value string, TTL int) error {
    err := c.Cache.Set(key, []byte(value))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("there are now ", c.Cache.Len(), " entries") 
    if TTL != 0 {
        go func() {
            fmt.Println("sleeping for ", TTL, " seconds")
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(TTL))
            c.Cache.Delete(key)
        }()
    }
    return nil
}
```

After each call to c.Cache.Len() from within MyCache.Set it returns 1.

My middleware that checks if the token inside of the jwt is a key in cache (as it should be, the tokens are always ok, i print it out to stdout to make sure):

```
func VerifyJWT(ca *cache.MyCache) echo.MiddlewareFunc {
    fn := func(next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
        return func(c echo.Context) error {
            user := c.Get("user").(*jwt.Token)
            claims := user.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
            token := claims["token"].(string)
            fmt.Println("token:")
            fmt.Println(token)
            val, err := ca.Cache.Get(token)
            fmt.Println("val:")
            fmt.Println(val)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                fmt.Println("there are ", ca.Cache.Len(), " entries")
                return c.NoContent(http.StatusUnauthorized)
            }
            return next(c)
        }
    }
    return echo.MiddlewareFunc(fn)
}
```

Now, each time i call `ca.Cache.Len()` it prints 0, and not finding the key, even though to the console it prints the exact same key.

Also, i was thinking i was overriding the instance of bigcache but its not the case, as i printed it out to the console and it showed me the same mem location of the same instace every time.

Am i doing something wrong here? A bug?

Thank you in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: As an aside: don't create a goroutine for each `Set` call to handle TTL - this is extremely wasteful. Instead, perhaps set TTL as an extra data field in the value & return a cache miss if we're beyond the TTL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are passing in a non-zero TTL value, which you assume is in seconds:

```
if TTL != 0 {
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("sleeping for ", TTL, " seconds")
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(TTL)) // <- nanoseconds not seconds
        c.Cache.Delete(key)
    }()
}
```

If your TTL is `300`, instead of 5 minutes this cache delete will occur in 300 nanoseconds!

You want:

```
time.Sleep(time.Duration(TTL)*time.Second) // <- convert raw number to actual seconds
```

or update your function signature to take a more declarative `time.Duration`:

```
func (c *MyCache) Set(key, value string, TTL time.Duration) error
```

---

P.S. see my comment above - generating a goroutine for every `Set()` is wasteful. It creates at least [2K in stack space](https://tpaschalis.github.io/goroutines-size/#:%7E:text=Some%20people%20learn%20that%20%E2%80%9Ca,represents%20its%20initial%20stack%20size.) for each call & creating a lot of unnecessary churn. There's better ways to handle TTL, like embedded the TTL value within the value itself & discarding values on lookup if the TTL has expired.

Comment: Thank you!
Its funny how something temporary is the thing which caused my program not to work ;)

Also, thank you for clarification about the goroutine topic.